# Will switching again affect my career?

Tags: software-industry, career-development

I moved to Berlin, 9 months back. I did freelancing development for first 2 months. Then I got a permanent position in a company. After 3 months the company closed their office because of financial issues. 
Then I joined my current company(1 month back), however I am a frontend engg. and current job expects core backend work from me. I have discussed with my manager and he has asked me to do backend instead of frontend.

If I switch my job again, would it be bad for my career since I have worked in 3 companies in last 9 months.

Edit:- In my 2nd company, I do have excellent reccomendations on both LinkdIn and in letter from the CTO and my manager. Things just didn't work out for the company.

Comment: It might. We can't really tell you how any given employer will see it. Although you should definitely try to avoid making it seem like you quit from the first 2 companies (possibly in your cover letter, not too sure - how to do that might make a good question).

Comment: "Did you know beforehand that your current job was backend work? Did you try to find out what the job would involve? Did you tell your manager that you're not happy doing backend work?" ... would be some questions one might expect in an interview.

Comment: Why don't you just do the backend work that's requested of you? Are you unable to complete the work? Do you dislike the work? This seems like a good opportunity to get some full stack credentials.

Comment: @GlenPierce I have only 1 year experience in the industry and I would like to keep focus on one tech stack for now

Comment: @Dukeling They told me it would be frontend work, however they junked the frontend project and don't have anything planned for next 6 months.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it will hurt your career. You have very little experience at this point and no positions lasting more than 3 months. If asked for why you're leaving your current position after only 2 months, your answer sounds like it's going to be something like, "they asked me to do backend work and I refused."

You're going to look like you're not employable, or unwilling to learn on the job, or unwilling to contribute to a team outside of a very narrow focus.

If a candidate like that came across my desk, I'd be concerned that if our particular stack had one or more technologies with which they were unfamiliar or uncomfortable, they might refuse to engage with it, fail to try to learn from it, or just quit.

I strongly recommend staying in your current role for at least a year. Learn some new technologies and gain some good experience.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You are quiet correct on what I might face. But I am worried about losing my current skills, If I don't get to use them in my current job.

Comment: Then start a side project.

Comment: And that side project could be contributing to some *existing* [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) project (e.g. on [github](http://github.com/)...) on your spare time. You'll learn a lot, and some employers might notice